# How to find whether my local branch is tracking remote branch or not?

Tags: git

Long time ago I clone the project from remote server.Recently I mostly worked on one particular branch of this project. Now I need to push the changes to this branch only (not to master).

I think I can do this with command

```
git push origin localBranchName:remoteBranchName
```

Also I can add `-u` to track this remote branch. But i might be tracking already so my question is how can I make sure I am tracking remote branch from this local branch. Is there git command or option that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `-vv` (very verbose) flag of [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

```
$ git branch -vv
```

Which will list all local branches, along with their default tracking branch.

Comment: This is a nifty feature I hadn't known about.  It even tells you if you're *behind* a remote tracking branch.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `git status` (reference: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

`git status` will show desired information for the branch you currenly on.

Example output:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

In this example local branch `master` tracks branch `master` on remote `origin`

You may also find useful shorter version: `git status -sb` which will output:

`## master...origin/master` if you branch tracks the remote

`## master` if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in another answer, `git branch` offers a way to print out the upstream branch for a local branch.  That information is also stored in `.git/config` in the section for the branch.  For example, for branch "myniftybranch" tracking upstream "origin/foo", you will find a section in `.git/config` that looks like this:

```
[branch "myniftybranch"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/foo
```

Hope that helps.